# My computer is playing audio without any program open

Tags: windows, virus

This is the weirdest thing ever that has happened to my computer (running Windows 7).

1. I haven't installed anything lastly, except lavasoft adware antivirus
2. When my computer stats then audio starts playing, mostly hip hop
3. There is no programs opened.
4. I tried killing all unknown processed, no success.
5. I tried resetting the firewall options of the antivirus, no success.
6. If I disconnect from internet, then it works.
7. The antivirus is not detecting anything.

Is somebody is streaming from another house?  Is that possible? and making my life impossible.

How can I check and stop this?

Comment: Right click on the volume icon, and choose "Open Volume Mixer". It should list all applications currently playing audio.

Comment: Try safe mode and see if it persists when you plug in a headset. It might just be static noise

Comment: @CodeInChaos: i do believe thats a viable answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to be a malware or trojan.

I downloaded 3 different programs to clean malware, one of them spyware search and destroy. I dont remember the name of the other 2, I scan my system with the 3 of them, and each one found different trojans.

I dont know which one fixed the problem but I dont have it anymore.

The other answers related to audio settings makes not even sense, thats why its tagged as a virus and indeed it was.

This is the thread that helped me.
http://forums.cnet.com/7723-6122_102-336301/help-pc-starts-playing-audio-by-itself/

Comment: If true, I have to say that you've got a problem on your hands. If you 'just' installed an anti-virus, and you already had 3+ trojans, then it's not your computer anymore. I'm not even sure what to suggest but to format the drive and start fresh, get a comercial-grade anti-virus and scan any backup files you have before loading them back on your fresh computer (you do have backups of your files, right?)

Answer (score 4):

You could try running the Resource Monitor and see what network connections are open and what program is using it (or netstat with the /b option). If you say it stops when you disconnect the Internet, then you should be able to find what program is streaming it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have any other Windows computers in your house (or, more specifically, on the same network)? Windows Media Player has a feature called "Play To" that can be used to stream music to another computer, so perhaps that's where the music is coming from?

See here for more information:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/using-the-play-to-feature-to-stream-media

Answer (score 1):

Is there a music CD in your computer's CD player?  This sounds a lot like your computer is just autoplaying the CD, and whoever built your machine hooked up the little cable that lets the audio from the CD player go directly to the sound hardware, allowing it to play through the speakers without needing any software running.

In addition have you checked the Sound settings?  Someone might have changed your 'startup sound' to just some really long audio file that is playing for a long time after startup.

1. Type "Change system sounds" in the start menu and press enter.
2. Scroll down to Windows Logon and see if the sound is what you're hearing.

Comment: lol no. there is no cd and I dont even like that kind of music, its just random tracks and they play like for 30 seconds each.  I am a computer science engineer and I already tried all I know.

Comment: hidden popups? http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090722140138AA6UxrK

Comment: A player running in another workspace? Most Ubuntu installs have 2 or more workspaces / desktops available to the user. There surely is an icon on your taskbar to switch between them.

Comment: Change the log level in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. You can check the results in syslog. Don't forget to change logging back. Don't forget to log off and log in. Double check the daemon start time with `ps -ef | grep puls`

Comment: its windows 7!!!

Comment: You say it's when the computer starts. Are you sure this isn't a case of someone remapping the default windows start event sound to a hip hop track? Is it always different?

Comment: @jippie: I think you misread the question ;p

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and run this, then post the results here 
   http://www.malwarebytes.org/
   This will scan for any malware on your system
2. Then launch Hijackthis, and post the results
   http://www.trendmicro.com/ftp/products/hijackthis/HiJackThis.msi
   This analyses the registry and various other parts your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if you are using Windows accounts like in Windows 7 etc and see if another user is logged in with a program running thereon the user account #2.

Comment: Hi. OP states he's checked all open programs and running processes. I'm pretty sure this covers this too. Plus the question's tagged as "virus" and OP's accepted his own answer that it was in fact some malicious piece of software on his computer.